# Why can I not connect to SQL Server using IP address, but works with server name?

Tags: authentication, amazon-web-services, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2008

I have a server hosted in Amazon's cloud (EC2, AWS), where I have SQL Server installed.  With SSMS on the server, I can connect to the server instance using the Amazon server name and the SQL Server instance.  However when I use the IP address, I cannot connect.

I have *Allow Remote Connections to Server* checked.

Similarly, I am unable to connect to the SQL Server instance remotely.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Check your security group. You need to open up the appropriate port to connect remotely.

Comment: Also make sure you are using the external IP, not the EC2 internal IP.

Comment: There is a default and named instance on the server.  Odd thing is that even though I have a user defined for the default instance, the connection error for that is the user cannot login.  However I get a total connection error for the named instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure you have enabled port 1433 to your specific public ip address in the appropriate security group.

You may also have to update the windows firewall config to allow the service to accept connections.

JL